# People reached tooltip in Profile tab can be used the style from Activity tab

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, tooltips

The tooltip (or popover) for the people reached in the Activity tab is looking good.

[image: good]

But for the people reached in the Profile tab is follows the old style. 
[image: not good]

Can be the tooltip style in the Activity tab is used for Profile tab too?

Comment: I never knew there is a tooltip on that in profile tab

Comment: @redhand there is tooltip anywhere in SE. :)